# How to find the base case of recurrence equation given it’s completely?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

If I know then recurrence equation and the complexity of the recurrence. please suggest an example

Answer (score 0):

The Recurrence Equation, also known as the Difference Equation would involve using recursive techniques to derive sequences; identifying recurrence relations until base case is true.

Example of linear recurrence equations : Recurrence Relations

- Fibonacci: Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2

Discrete Mathematical questions are better asked in Mathematics StackExchange or the Computer Science StackExchange.

Resources:

- https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecurrenceEquation.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm